# Displaying a ascii table

Tags: java

I am trying to display a ascii table in lines of 16 and a column of the left side starting at 32 and ending at 240. The problem is I cannot get the table to go beyond the 1st 16 characters it just keeps repeating the same line.This is the code.
public static void main (String[] args) {
        int counter = 0;

```
    for (int i = 32; i <= 255; i = i + 16) {

        if(i < 112)
            System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.print(i + " " );


        for (int j = 32; j <= 47; j++) {
            counter++;
            System.out.print((char)j );
            if(counter % 16 == 0)
            System.out.print((char)j );

            else
                System.out.print((char)j + " ");


        }
        System.out.println();
```

and this is the output.

```
32    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
 48    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
 64    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
 80    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
 96    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
112    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
128    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
144    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
160    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
176    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
192    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
208    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
224    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
240    !! "" ## $$ %% && '' (( )) ** ++ ,, -- .. //
enter code here
```

Comment: Shouldn't **j** change with value of **i**? Something like `for (int j = i; j <= i+15; j++)`

Comment: Your  code change works but it doubles each character.

Comment: Commenting line `System.out.print((char) j);` right after `counter++;` might help because it is always going to print as well.

Comment: You are correct I had put that there trying to find out why the code was not working forgot to delete it. Anyway thank you very much for the help!

Comment: This isn't the ASCII character set, which only has 128 codepoints. Java's `char` is a [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html)/UTF-16 code unit. Within the range you are using, only one UTF-16 code unit is needed for the corresponding Unicode codepoint so your usage seems okay. BTW—you could have fun by printing the [control pictures](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/n_2400.html#2401) for ␀  to ␟.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is wrong. You always start at `j=32` but you should start at `j=i` ,I believe.

And also stop at `j <= i+15`.